# Android - CheckBox Not Saving check State

Tags: javascript, android

I currently have a checkbox implemented in my code with a click listener. The click listener simply pulls my shared prefs and saves them so that they can be applied on reboot (via a service).

I am wondering how I can modify the following code to also remember the "State" of the checkbox.

```
setboot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Applied on boot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

                HashM hash2 = new HashM();
                hash2.getPrefs(MainActivity.this);

            }

        }).start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Where is checkbox? Or its state's variable?

Comment: have not added a state variable... all I have is what i posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a class variable that keeps track of "state" of CheckBox (I am assuming "state" here means if check box is clicked or not).
`boolean ischeckboxcheck= false;`

Next, use below code to fetch the state of your check box.

```
setboot = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);       
ischeckboxcheck = setboot.isChecked();
```

Now, you have a "state" of Check box.
Then, copy this state info into your sharedpreference object, as below:
`mySharedPreference.edit().putBoolean("checkboxvalue", ischeckboxcheck);`

Later, from your  sharedpreference  object you should be able to "read" the state info from your sharedpreference using key "checkboxvalue" as below:
`mySharedPreference.getBoolean("checkboxvalue", false)`